# The problem with a singly linked list с++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I have a code that performs the following task: characters are entered line by line to the dot, then a list is displayed. I need to add such a method so that when it is called, the list is supplemented with all its characters in reverse order (for example, there was a list of abс. should become abс.сba). You cannot expand the list. The method should be based on this principle: we go through the list again from the first element and add an element after the point each time (first abс.a, then abс.ba, then abс.сba). I tried to write the Add Elements function, but I finally got confused in it, or I catch an infinite loop with an empty output, or vice versa with an infinite output, or only the first character is output

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

struct element {
    char x;
    element* Next;
};

class List {
    element* Head;
public:
    List() {
        Head = NULL;
    }
    ~List();

    void Add(char x, element*& Head);
    void Show(element* Beg);
    void AddElements(element* beg, element*& Head);

};

List::~List() {
    while (Head != NULL) {
        element* temp = Head->Next;
        delete Head;
        Head = temp;
    }
}


void List::Add(char x, element*& Head) {
    element* temp = new element;
    temp->x = x;
    temp->Next = NULL;
    Head->Next = temp;
    Head = temp;
}


void List::Show(element* beg) {
    element* temp = beg;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        std::cout << temp->x << "";
        temp = temp->Next;
    }
    Head = beg;
}

void List::AddElements(element* beg, element*& Head) {
    element* temp1 = beg;
    element* temp2 = Head;
    element* temp0 = temp1;
    temp2->Next = temp0;
    while (temp1 != temp2) {
        temp0->Next = temp2->Next;
        temp0 = temp1;
        temp2->Next = temp0;
        
        if (temp1->Next != NULL) {
            temp1 = temp1->Next;
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    std::cout << "Односвязный список." << std::endl;
    char x;
    List lst;
    element* H = new element;
    element* beg = H;
    std::cout << "Введите символ: "; std::cin >> x;
    H->x = x;
    H->Next = NULL;
    while (x != '.') {
        std::cin >> x;
        lst.Add(x, H);
    }
    lst.AddElements(beg, H);
    std::cout << "Результат: ";
    lst.Show(beg);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to make a function that from the list of abs. will make a list of abс.сba and output it(

Comment: Your show function should not have: `for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {` instead you need to loop `while (temp) {`

Comment: @Pain "You cannot expand the list." - that contradicts the task description.:)

Comment: You seem to have two `Head` pointers, one as a member and one as a parameter. You should probably only have one.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of member variables in classes. Don't create your separate "head", don't pass it to the functions.

Comment: @Pain In this case it will be much better to define a two-sided singly-linked list.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll go through the order, I added the for loop to conduct one test, in the original, of course, while. It is forbidden to create a doubly linked list, it is necessary to expand the simply linked list in the way I described above. How to do this, I have no idea(

Comment: @Pain *it is necessary to expand the simply linked list in the way I described above.* -- The assignment, or your attempt of the assignment is fundamentally flawed.  The main reason is that `main` shouldn't need to know anything about `element`.  The `Add` function should simply be `Add(char value);` -- it is the responsibility of `List` and only `List` to create and maintain `element`'s to support the value that is being added to it.  If you approached the assignment this way, you wouldn't be in the situation where you are confusing the `head` variables in `main` and in `List`.

Comment: Also, `Add` should be implemented in terms of `AddElements`.  All `Add` element should have been doing is call `AddElements`, but using a single value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've been working on this task for so long that I don't get it anymore, the Add function worked fine until I added AddEelements, before it the code normally added elements and displayed the list to the point

Comment: 1) `Add(char value);` -- `AddElements(const char *buffer, int length);` -- Those make more sense.  As mentioned, the `Add` should add the character to the linked list.  The `AddElements` takes the characters that are in the buffer and adds one-at-a-time to the linked list (the length is the number of characters).  These are better interfaces to the functions you are trying to write.  Right now, you have a linked list that has half of its workings being done by `main`, and that really is not how to write such classes.  The `main` shouldn't care or know about *how* the linked list adds items.

Comment: Basically, it's too bad you went down the rabbit-hole of implementing a poor interface.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie main() and Add are presented in the task in advance and they cannot be changed (Just a call to one addelements function is added to main, and I do not know how to implement it now, as I described, but the deadline is tomorrow(

Comment: Again, the problem is the way you defined the functions.   To me, it makes no sense to be adding `beg` to your linked list -- you should be adding characters and the linked list is responsible for creating the nodes.   I am surprised you didn't see this and ask your teacher "why not add characters?".  Right now, the only way for `AddElements` to work is if you give it a linked list of `elements` to add.  If that is the case, then maybe you can simply call `Add()` in a loop, going through the linked list that was passed in.

Comment: Just like before, the teacher said that this is possible only after he completes the task assigned by the head each time, namely abc.a -> abc.ba -> abc.cba

Comment: Well, we don't listen to teachers here.  Remember that the persons responding to you are experienced C++ programmers, and teachers of C++, unfortunately for the most part, do a poor job of teaching C++, if C++ at all.  Second, it may come down to just removing everything you have in `AddElements`, take a step back, and think about how to accomplish this by calling `Add()` in a loop.  Since you claim that `Add()` works, why not use it to your advantage in `AddElements()`?  If the goal of `Add()` is to add an element, then it should work if you call it in a loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In this case, I need to go through the list in reverse order and call the Add method with the infield of each element as an argument, but I have already expanded the list by copying its expanded version to another list and the teacher forbade doing so and did not accept the change (

Comment: Then you should go back to the answer given by KozyDot and inspect the `beg`.  I commented on it.  That answer basically outlines what I have been mentioning about using `Add()` to add an element.  If it doesn't work, then `Add` was broken all along without you knowing it.

Comment: You should review the advice in [ask] about writing good question titles. Your current title has three pieces of information. The first, *"The problem"*, is implied by the fact that you're asking a question. The other two, *"singly linked list"* and *"с++"*, are given by tags so contribute nothing (see the "Should I use tags in titles?" section of [help: tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)). So basically, your current title is uninformative.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing seems to be due to incorrect manipulation of the linked list in your `AddElements` method.

The task is to reverse the order of the characters and add them to the end of the list. This can be achieved by traversing the list, storing the characters in a stack, and then populating the reversed characters from the stack back into the list.

```cpp
void List::AddElements(element* beg) {
    std::stack<char> s;
    element* temp = beg;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        s.push(temp->x);
        temp = temp->Next;
    }
    while(!s.empty()) {
        Add(s.top(), Head);
        s.pop();
    }
}
```

Here's what's happening:

- Traverse the list from the beginning to the end, pushing each character onto a stack. This is because a stack follows a Last-In-First-Out (LIFO) protocol, which means the last element added will be the first one to be removed. This inherently reverses the order of the characters.
- Pop each character from the stack and add it to the end of the list
  using the `Add` method.

Comment: I tried your method, an exception is raised in line 35 (description of the Add method):
Unhandled exception at address 0x004A5818 in Project2.exe : 0xC0000005: access violation when writing to address 0x00000004.

Comment: @Pain You should inspect what you are passing to `AddElements`.  The code given in the answer *must* work correctly **if** `beg` is a properly-implemented list.  That means you should use your debugger to see `beg`, `beg->Next`, `beg->Next->Next`, etc. to make sure it is correctly built.  The only other possibility is that `Add` is broken, or `Head` gets screwed up in `Add` (which means `Add` is broken).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OK, thanks, I'll try in the debugger later, just without the Addelement function everything works correctly and a list is output. With this function, an exception occurs that temp turns out to be NULL at some iteration, and the program shuts down